# Python 3 Pandas, appending data to existing Excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm pretty new to this, but for me it looks like the only way to append data to an Excel sheet is reading the Excel, get the columns out and append to these lists the data I want to append and then rewrite the Excel sheet.

Is this true or is there a way to append a data frame to the table just like I would do with a txt file and the `file.open('a')` command which automatically puts it at the end of the existing file?

Comment: Have you looked at XlsxWriter?

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use openpyxl engine and set the starting row parameter as

```
len(existing df) +1
```